# c# serialize more than 1 list at the same xml file

Tags: c#, serialization, uwp

I am trying serialize 3 list to a unique xml file.
My project is a UWP, and I wrote a method but it current serialize only 1 list.
How I could serialize 3 list with my method.

My current serialization method:

```
public static async void SaveObjectToXml<T>(T objectToSave)
{
    //<-----------FilePicker------------------>
    var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
    savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("New File", new List<string>() { ".xml" });
    savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New File";
    StorageFile newfile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
    //<-----------FilePicker------------------>
    //<----------------Serializacion------------------>

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    Stream stream = await newfile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();


    using (stream)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
    }
    //<----------------Serializacion------------------>

}
```

My lists:

```
public class List1 : BindableBase
{        
    private int _Property1;
    public int Property1
    {
        get { return _Property1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property1, value); }
    }

    private bool _Property2;
    public bool Property2
    {
        get { return _Property2; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property2, value); }
    }

    private bool _Property3;
    public bool Property3
    {
        get { return _Property3; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property3, value); }
    }
}




public class List2 : BindableBase
{        

    private bool _Property1;
    public bool Property1
    {
        get { return _Property1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property1, value); }
    }

    private bool _Property2;
    public bool Property2
    {
        get { return _Property2; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property2, value); }
    }
}

    public class List3 : BindableBase
{        
    private double _Property1;
    public double Property1
    {
        get { return _Property1; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property1, value); }
    }

    private double _Property2;
    public double Property2
    {
        get { return _Property2; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property2, value); }
    }

    private double _Property3;
    public double Property3
    {
        get { return _Property3; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property3, value); }
    }

    private double _Property4;
    public double Property4
    {
        get { return _Property4; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Property4, value); }
    }

}

public class Values_List1 : ObservableCollection<List1>
    {
    }
    public class Values_List2 : ObservableCollection<List2>
    {
    }
    public class Values_List3 : ObservableCollection<List3>
    {
    }

public static class ApplicationServices
    {
public static Values_List1 List1 = new Values_List1();
public static Values_List2 List2 = new Values_List2();
public static Values_List3 List3 = new Values_List3();

static ApplicationServices()
        {
        }
    }


List1.Add(new List1()
            {
                Property1 = 1,
                Property2 = true,
                Property3 = false,
            });


List2.Add(new List2()
            {                
                Property1 = true,
                Property2 = false,
            });


List3.Add(new List3()
            {
                Property1 = 3.564,
                Property2 = 0.215,
                Property3 = 0.7252,
                Property3 = 23.463,
            });
```

> I wanna  get something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <List1>
    <Property1>1</Property1>
    <Property2>true</Property2>
    <Property3>false</Property3>
    <ToAcero>0.1</ToAcero>
  </List1>
  <List2>
    <Property1>true</Property1>
    <Property2>true</Property2>
  </List2>
  <List3>
    <Property1>3.564</Property1>
    <Property2>0.215</Property2>
    <Property3>0.7252</Property3>
    <Property4>23.463</Property4>
  </List3>
</Root>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a class like this;

```
class myCompoundClass
{
     public List1 List1 {get;set;}
     public List2 List2 {get;set;}
     public List3 List3 {get;set;}

}
```

and serialize the myCompoundClass instance.

Comment: It seems more logical to me to serialize lists as array not as wrapper object with properties.

Comment: Thank you, I am doing that but my method return error: "myCompoundClass is a type, which is not valid in the given context.".

Comment: @Julius can you post the Code where you use this solution?

Comment: @PhillipH for serialization to work the class should be `public`

Comment: I has been edited the original post. Thank you,
yes, with me solution of @PhillipH I put public.